# Where should my Try Catch block be when running a thread?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, try-catch

Take this thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                //Code
            });

            thread.Start();
```

Should it be around the `thread.Start();` or inside:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                try
                {
                    //Code
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Code
                }
            });
```

Comment: That would depend on if you are trying to trap errors in the line `thread.Start()` or in the body of the method it runs.

Comment: @spender: I get errors inside the body. The methods in there has try catch blocks as well, and then nothing happens when the errors are caught. It crashes my entire app. So would it be best to have a try inside the body and around the .Start()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is completely different to put then inside or outside.

If you put them around the `thread.Start()` call, you can detect (according to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start(v=vs.71).aspx)

- ThreadStateException The thread has already been started.
- SecurityException    The caller does not have the appropriate SecurityPermission.
- OutOfMemoryException There is not enough memory available to start this thread.
- NullReferenceException   This method was invoked on a thread reference that is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).

If you put it inside, you will detect exception inside the code you will run in your thread. So any kind of exception you want.

Answer (score 4):

The exceptions pertaining the logic you have in the delegate should be handled inside the delegate.

`thread.Start()` itself can only throw `ThreadStateException` or `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 3):

[Preventing silent thred termination](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Threading-and-Synchronization/Preventing-Silent-Thread-Termination/)

It explains to place the try catch inside of the delegate.  It also talks about doing your finnally clean up if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you mention above, the error is in the delegate code, then put the try-catch in there and log the exception. Alternatively, if you want that exception to be passed back to the original thread use an asynchronous delegate (calling EndInvoke will re-raise the exception to the calling  thread or use Background worker and subscribe to RunWorkerCompleted event (this has error property in event args).