# How can i check if i catch a exception in thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I have an abstract class which runs threads:

```
protected volatile bool HasError = false;

public void Run()
{
    var readingThread = new Thread(ReadInFile);
    var compressingThreads = new List<Thread>();
    for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
    {
        var j = i;
        ProcessEvents[j] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        compressingThreads.Add(new Thread(() => Process(j)));
    }
    var writingThread = new Thread(WriteOutFile);

    readingThread.Start();

    foreach (var compressThread in compressingThreads)
    {
        compressThread.Start();
    }

    writingThread.Start();

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(ProcessEvents);
    OutputDictionary.SetCompleted();

    writingThread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine(!HasError ? "Successfully competed" : "Error");
}
```

Well, and I don't know how I can check the Exception?
This is class realizes abstract class.
This is one method :

```
protected override void Process(int processEventId)
{
    try
    {
       while (InputQueue.Dequeue(out Chunk chunk) && !HasError)
       {
            var compressedChunk = GZip.GZip.CompressByBlocks(chunk.Bytes);
            OutputDictionary.Add(chunk.Id, compressedChunk);
       }

       ProcessEvents[processEventId].Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       HasError = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I change the value of a variable when I catch an exception, but will it work? I do not understand how to check.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493138/where-should-my-try-catch-block-be-when-running-a-thread)

Comment: I dont understand what your question is? Is your code working? If not what is the problem?

Comment: I would suggest you not to manage the threads yourself on that low level. Instead, use the abstractions the .NET Framework provides: Task Parallel Library, Task-based Asynchronous Programming, Parallel LINQ, Dataflow, ...

Comment: Yep..that is a good idea. But I can't do that. Because that is a test task for company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better answer is probably not to use Threads but use `Parallel.For()`, it manages your errors and also has better options to handle workload.

But in your current setup, just add a wrapper method:

```
    var j = i; 
    ProcessEvents[j] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    compressingThreads.Add(new Thread(() => SafeCallProcess(j) ));
```

and

```
private void SafeCallProcess(int j) 
{
   try 
   {
      Process (j);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      // deal with it
   }
}
```

You could move the `Set()` to the wrapper too, up to your taste I guess.

Comment: yep, that is a good idea. But that my test task for company and they say : "use only clear threads without Tasks, Background, and TPL library"